# Office-js Excel API: filter.apply(...) does not trigger recalculation of SUBTOTAL functions

Tags: office-js

Code below filters the table correctly but does not cause subtotal calculations to update as does happen when changing filters in the sheet directly.

Is there a workaround or other API call to trigger this?  I looked for a table or worksheet recalc() function but could not find one.

Thanks.

```
     Excel.run((ctx: Excel.RequestContext) =>
     {
        var table = ctx.workbook.tables.getItem(tableIdOrName);

        if (!keepPrevFilters)
           table.clearFilters();

        var column = table.columns.getItemAt(colIdx);
        column.filter.apply(filterCriteria);

        return ctx.sync().then(() =>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can force 3 types of recalculation with the `calculate` method on the `Application` object.

Documentation: https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/application

-Michael, PM for Office add-ins

Comment: thanks for the reply. I have tried some things and here are my findings:

Comment: `application.calculate(full)` and `application.calculate(recacluate)` do not cause recalc. `application.calculate(fullRebuild)` does recalc but this recalcs all open workbooks and it overrides the user option "Worbook Calculation" so if the user has manual recalc on calling this API will still recalc. Based on this I'm reluctant to use it.

Comment: I think the problem is that `filter.apply(..)` is not marking the table or _something_ as dirty so Excel doesn't think it has anything to recalc. I am lead to this conclusion because 1) I enabled Manual Calculation, 2) then called a `filter.apply(..)`, then 3) pressed F9 and nothing happens. Repeating these steps and applying filters using the table in sheet and then F9 does the recalc.

Comment: @JimBarrett, let me pass this on to the dev team

Comment: Another detail that might help...I just noticed the "Clear" filter button on the Data menu doesn't recognize when a filter is set via the API because the button does not become enabled.